# Перечисление в Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Функция:

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <td><h2><%= article.title %></h2></td>
    <td><h4><%= article.jobs.map(&:text) %></h4></td>

<% end %>
```

выводит артикли как надо, все по порядку, и для каждого артикля мне необходимо вывести список работ, которые относятся к данному артиклю.
модель работы:

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :article
end
```

модель артикля:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :jobs, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Все-таки получилось сделать задуманное:

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>

    <h2><%= article.title %></h2>
    <ul>
      <td><%= article.jobs.map do |job| %>
        <li><%= job.text %>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
    <%= link_to 'Show', article_path(article) %><br>

<% end %>
```

Но теперь список выглядит так:

```
yh6yenrtnu
trnuymyum
dzfbxgb
xgbxgb
xgfbxfgb ["\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n"]
```

Не понимаю каким образом в конце высвечивается ["/n"], и количество таких пунктов зависит от количества объектов в списке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нотация `<%=` в ERB выводит результат выполнения строки во вьюху. Поэтому, когда вы хотите увидеть заголовок статьи, то используете `<%= article.title %>`. Если же вы хотите выполнить рубишный код, но не выводить его результат (назначение переменной, итерация), то вам нужна `<%` (без знака =)

Используйте `each` вместо `map` и разберитесь с закрывающими тегами

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>    
  <h2><%= article.title %></h2>
  <ul>
    <% article.jobs.each do |job| %>
      <li><%= job.text %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  <%= link_to 'Show', article_path(article) %><br>    
<% end %>
```

Если хотите видеть текст джобов в одной строке, то используйте `join` - он объединит полученный массив в строку. Почитайте про [`pluck`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck) - с его помощью можно выбрать из таблицы только нужный столбец, а не выгружать все данные.

```
<%= article.jobs.pluck(&:text).join(', ') %>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Теги все также прописывались в последнюю строчку и добавляло еще больше неудобств.
А each показывало изначально Enumerate

Comment: @Александр `each` просто перебирает элементы, а `map` создаёт новый массив